# magento statuses - pending, processing & credit card orders

Tags: magento, status

I have a question regarding Magento Order statuses and credit card payments.

**Orders paid by cheque or money Order**
For Orders paid by cheque or money order, Magento starts status orders in "Pending", 
then moves status to "Processing" when administrator Invoices order.

**Orders paid by Credit card** 
For Orders paid by Credit Card, Credit Card Module starts orders in status "Processing"

**Question**
We want to extract orders via Magento API. To determine which orders to extract 
we use the "sales_order.list" API method requesting only orders where status = "pending" 
and then setting orders to status to "processing" via "sales_order.addComment" API method.

With Credit Card process setting order status to "Processing", we are no longer able to 
identify unprocessed orders, by status alone.

Is it possible to add or re-purpose a status or add new status?

example:

Pending - order by cheque or money order

PendingCC - Processed by Credit Card

Processing - only set by our API

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: Admin -> System -> Order Statuses

Then go to Admin -> System -> Config -> Payment Methods -> New order status

Comment: thanks, I tried that ... it creates new status, but I would still have to write business rules and workflow.  I cannot find any substantial or examples documentation on the subject.